# Call subroutines inside Event

Tags: vba, excel

I've the Pivot Table in Sheet 1 and in VBA I've the following code to sort another PivotTable in the same sheet based on Update event.

#### Event Code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

    If Target = "PivotTable1" Then

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("75Percentile").PivotFields( _
        "[DimCustomer].[Customer Desc].[Customer Desc]").ClearAllFilters

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("75Percentile").PivotFields( _
        "[DimCustomer].[Customer Desc].[Customer Desc]").PivotFilters.Add2 Type:= _
        xlValueIsGreaterThan, DataField:=ActiveSheet.PivotTables("75Percentile"). _
        CubeFields("[Measures].[Sales Qty (Van Sales)]"), Value1:=Range("F5").Value
       
        
    Call Module1.SortGold
    End If
     
End Sub
```

Inside this code I try to call `Module1.SortGold` that is:

#### Module Code

```
Sub SortGold()

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Gold").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Gold").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "E2:E5001"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Gold").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
End Sub
```

That should sort values in another sheet (Gold). Unfortunately It seems that the module wont trigger. If I run with F5 the module the table is sorted correctly so the problem is launching the module...

Any thoughts?

Comment: If they're in the same project you should just be able to call it with `Call SortGold` there's no need for the `Module1`

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the pivot table function and do something that should trigger it. When it is triggered, step through the function to see if maybe the function call isn't happening (like premature, errorless termination).

Comment: You don't need the keyword `Call` at all. Just `SortGold` would be sufficient to call that subroutine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this modification:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target = "PivotTable1" Then

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("75Percentile").PivotFields( _
        "[DimCustomer].[Customer Desc].[Customer Desc]").ClearAllFilters

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("75Percentile").PivotFields( _
        "[DimCustomer].[Customer Desc].[Customer Desc]").PivotFilters.Add2 Type:= _
        xlValueIsGreaterThan, DataField:=ActiveSheet.PivotTables("75Percentile"). _
        CubeFields("[Measures].[Sales Qty (Van Sales)]"), Value1:=Range("F5").Value


    Call Module1.SortGold
    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```